# Select all (*) pymySQL using separed request and value

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, pymysql

I can not figure out on the pymysql documentation a way to use separate request and value for a select all request.

Like: `cursor.execute(request, (value))`

I would do : `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s", (table))`

But it is not working

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {table}", {table=table})`

Comment: Is that securised ?

Comment: I am given to believe it is.

Comment: @Coldspeed's snippet won't just because syntax errors and if corrected, it'll still generate broken SQL because table name will be in quotes.

Comment: Do you know how to do but in this way @bakatrouble ?

Answer (score 0):

Pymysql doesn't allow identifier substitution. But, you could use native Python formatting:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM `%s`' % table
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: `pymysql` doesn't provide this functionality, so you should assure user input won't break anything by yourself.